# No more sugar canes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've found all the sugar canes in my world and used it now I've got none to grow. How on earth do I get sugar cane now?! I've looked everywhere for a solution but still no sugar canes. Help?

Comment: Is this on pocket edition?

Comment: If it's regular PC/Mac minecraft, or even console versions, it should be endless to an extent. I doubt Taylor has ever gone through the entirety of a world.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Weren't the far lands (or w/e they were called) patched out already, thus resulting in a world without any boundaries?

Comment: @user1337 as far as I can tell yes, but still, getting out that far would take forever, even when flying in creative. There has to be some source of sugar cane somewhere.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Thus the only issue with the question is whether or not he's playing Pocket Edition.

Answer (score 3):

Your options are:

- Explore farther.
- Cheat them in.

If you are on console or iOS you are completely out of luck.

Answer (score -3):

"Cheat them in." means use the console, see wiki: [Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#gamemode)
It says type "/gamemode 0" for creative, place a few, then use "/gamemode 1" to go back to playing normally.

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to contain an answer. You might mention Sugar Cane, or where you got the phrase "Cheat them in."

Comment: I notice this should have been a comment for this answer, in fact: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/222819/16979